# How to handle and get values from dynamic tags from XML file in VBA macro

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have an XML file with 3 levels. Some of the tags are dynamic.*(Please check below XML file)*

I have to validate whether the tag "price" is present in all nodes or not and also need to get value of "price tag". I also need to fetch a value of every node present in XML file.

I tried validating whether every node in XML file is present or not but getting an error
**VBA code snippet**

```vb
Function fnReadXMLByTags2()

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

Dim obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
obj.async = False

XMLFileName = "C:\Prakash\Demo.xml"

obj.Load (XMLFileName)

Set authorNodes = obj.SelectNodes("//Books/book/author/text()")
Set titleNodes = obj.SelectNodes("//Books/book/title/text()")
Set genreNodes = obj.SelectNodes("//Books/book/genre/text()")
Set priceNodes = obj.SelectNodes("//Books/book/price/text()")
Set publish_dateNodes = obj.SelectNodes("//Books/book/publish_date/text()")
Set languageNodes = obj.SelectNodes("//Books/book/language/text()")

    For i = 0 To (authorNodes.Length - 1)

        If Not publish_dateNodes Is Nothing Then
            Set publish_dateNodesValue = obj.SelectNodes("//Books/book/publish_date/text()")
            publish_dateObj = publish_dateNodesValue(i).NodeValue
            mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & i + 2).Value = publish_dateObj
        Else
            mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & i + 2).Value = "Blank"
        End If

    Next
End Function
```

**Below error Message for line …**

```
publish_dateObj = publish_dateNodesValue(i).NodeValue
```

> Runtime error '91':
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

**This is what I'm expecting in Excel file:**

Excel sheet output

[image: Excel sheet expected]

Below is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Books>
   <book id="1">
      <author>ABC</author>
      <title>Physics</title>
      <genre>asd</genre>
      <price>Rs.44</price>
      <publish_date>20-10-2001</publish_date>
      <description>Book1</description>
   </book>
   <book id="2">
      <author>DEF</author>
      <title>Chem</title>
      <genre>XYZ</genre>
      <publish_date>02-12-2016</publish_date>
      <description>Book2</description>
   </book>
   <book id="3">
      <author>GHI</author>
      <title>Maths</title>
      <genre>ABC</genre>
      <price>Rs.500</price>
      <language>English</language>
      <description>Book3</description>
   </book>
</Books>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome. There's no attempt at code here, it's worth reading the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask guide. Aside from this, it's possible to import XML without VBA in excel: https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/import-xml-files/

Comment: @RowanC, Thank you for your inputs. I'm just trying to understand the logic to validate every node from the xml file and get values of some specific tags. And yes, I did try xml import option in excel but that is not going to solve my problem. I have xml files which has more that 5000+ records so its a bit challenging to validate dynamic tags.

Comment: now all that seems to be missing is the exact error message, and the location in the code where you get that error.

Comment: What do you expect `authorNodesValue(i)` to be? `authorNodesValue` is an object but an `(i)` does not exist. What is your goal here. Also `/Order/srcOrderId` does not exist in your example XML file. Please clarify and [edit] your question. • Do you want to generate the complete output that you show from the XML file? or is there already data in the output sheet? Here it is unclear what your exact goal is.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I'm checking whether a node exists in xml file or not. If the tag does exists then I'm trying to fetch value of that node and if the tag does not exists then I'm printing a blank value in excel sheet. attached excel sheet is the expected output. As per the xml file, data will get added in excel sheet. Since there are total 3 "books" records in xml file, "i" represents every record starting from books id=1 to id=3.

Comment: But what is `/Order/srcOrderId`? It is neither in your XML nor in your output sheet. Please be more precise.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, By mistakenly I added  /Order/srcOrderId from my original xml file. I have updated the question now.

Comment: @Prakash Well, with the updated code there is no error and it works, you really need to be more precise.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, Sorry for the trouble. And yeah that's true because I did some change in my xml file so It's working for "author tag" but if you try for "publish_dateNodes" you will encounter this issue (Code updated again). I'm trying my best to be more precise and learning from my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It should be a procedure (`Sub`) not a function, because it does not return a value (make sure you know the difference).
2. The way you read the sub nodes made it impossible to keep the data consitent. You need to read all books first and then for each book the sub nodes:

   ```
   Set CurrentNode = Books(iBook).SelectNodes("author/text()")(0)
   ```

   The above reads reads the node `author` from book number `iBook` into `CurrentNode` and if it does not exist then `CurrentNode` will be `Nothing`. So you just need to check it and output the `.NodeValue`.

   Note that I introduced an array `NodesOutputList` to be able to loop through the columns easily instead of repeating similar code over and over.

So you end up with something like:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub fnReadXMLByTags2()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Set mainWorkBook = ThisWorkbook '<-- this is the workbook where this code is in ActiveWorkbook is the worbkook that has focus (is on top)

    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet 'define output sheet
    Set wsOutput = mainWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

    Dim XMLFileName As String
    XMLFileName = "D:\code\Demo.xml"

    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    obj.async = False
    obj.Load XMLFileName '<-- no parenthesis here!!!

    Dim Books As Object 'get all books
    Set Books = obj.SelectNodes("//Books/book")

    Dim NodesOutputList() As Variant 'order in which the nodes are checked and output
    NodesOutputList = Array("author/text()", "title/text()", "genre/text()", "price/text()", "publish_date/text()", "language/text()", "description/text()")

    Dim iBook As Long
    For iBook = 0 To Books.Length - 1 'loop through books

        Dim iNode As Long
        For iNode = LBound(NodesOutputList) To UBound(NodesOutputList) 'loop through nodes in the list
            Dim CurrentNode As Object
            Set CurrentNode = Books(iBook).SelectNodes(NodesOutputList(iNode))(0)
            If Not CurrentNode Is Nothing Then
                wsOutput.Cells(iBook + 2, iNode + 1).Value = CurrentNode.NodeValue
            Else
                wsOutput.Cells(iBook + 2, iNode + 1).Value = "blank"
            End If
        Next iNode

    Next iBook
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Getting some errors while running the given solution but let me try to fix them. If I need any help then will trouble you again :P Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Hello, I was debugging the code and found out "Set Books = obj.SelectNodes("//Books/book")" returns (0) so its not going inside the For loop. Even if I change loop value from 0 to 3 (any positive value) "Set CurrentNode = Books(iBook).SelectNodes(NodesOutputList(iNode))(0)" line is throwing an error. Error message : Runtime error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: @Prakash Make sure you used the correct path in `XMLFileName = "D:\code\Demo.xml"`

Comment: @PEH, the path is correct. I'm able to access the XML file. :(

Comment: @Prakash Well I tested it with exactly the content you provided in your question and it worked with that code (see the screenshot which was my result from the XML in your question). Please re-check and use the exact same data to test.

Comment: Sure, Let me check again. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

'try this simple code

```
Sub getXMLTagValue()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim xmlTagName As String
    Dim xmlTagValue As String
    Dim xmlLogs As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fileName As String
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\D_Drive\Many\Files")
    
    i = 2
    For Each file In folder.Files
        xmlLogs = ""
        xmlDoc.Load "C:\D_Drive\Many\Files\" & file.Name
        Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*")
        For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList
            xmlTagName = xmlNode.nodeName
            xmlTagValue = xmlNode.Text
            If xmlTagName = "name" Then
                xmlLogs = xmlLogs & "<name>" & xmlTagValue & "</name>" & vbCrLf
                ElseIf xmlTagName = "id" Then
                xmlLogs = xmlLogs & "<id>" & xmlTagValue & "</id> " & vbCrLf
                Exit For
            End If
        Next xmlNode
       Cells(i, 1).Value = file.Name
       Cells(i, 2).Value = xmlLogs
    i = i + 1
    Next file
End Sub
```